# Script to find difference in sum of columns of two files

Tags: linux, bash, unix, scripting

I have two file of some records

```
   rec10|rec11|rec12|....|abcd1234|rec19|rec110|rec111|name1|xyz|.......|rec1n
   rec20|rec21|rec22|....|abcd1234|rec29|rec210|rec211|name1|xyz|.......|rec2n
   rec30|rec31|rec32|....|xyzw1234|rec39|rec310|rec311|name1|uvw|.......|rec3n
   ...........................................................................
   ...........................................................................
```

Some columns are key columns which i can cut and put in another file (say keyFile)

```
  cat recordFile|cut -d"|", -f1,5,7 >keyFile
```

Now for each key K in keyFile I have to filter rows having K as key and get a columnwise sum

I need do same for recordFile2

and i want key and column wise difference

let's say file 1 is

```
x,y,z,5,6,7
a,y,z,3,5,8
a,x,t,1,1,1
```

and file 2 is

```
x,y,s,1,2,3
p,y,z,3,5,8
a,y,z,1,1,1
```

let's say column 2 and column 3 are key columns and if i cut those columns the distinct keys are (y,z) (x,t) (y,s)
for each key I need to find the difference in column wise sum

say for(y,z) 
 I can sum to get 8,11,15
Similarly for file 2 to get 4,6,9
and difference is 4,5,6
so output is (y,z)  4  5 6

similarly for other keys

```
while read line  //read one key each time from inKeyFile
       IFS=', ' read -a array <<< "$line"
       for element in "${array[@]}"
       do

// filter rows which matched whole key array .**How to put the filter condition in awk for complete key value in array**
<code>
       IFS=' ' read -a arrayA<<<  awk -F"|" -v k="$num1" -v n="$num2" '$col1=array[0] && $col2=array[1]&& so on.. {for(i=k;i<=n;i++)s[i]+=$i} END{for(x in s)printf " %f ",s[x]}' recordFile1

      //read the awk output into an array A of size num2-num1+1
    //same for Recordsfile2 to read in an array B
      IFS=' ' read -a arrayB<<<  awk .....
     print line-->(the key)
      for(i=num1 to num2) print $A[i] -$B[i]

<<inKeyFile
```

How do I put the filter in awk ,say I run it as ./Myscript.sh inFile 2:x,3:y,5:z 10 15
to have columnwise sum of columns 10 to column 15 where key columns have specified values
column 2,3,5 are key columns (I can cut them and put it in inKeyFile) and column 2 should be x,column 3 should be y and column 5 should be z.How do i apply this filter in awk?

How to avoid processing keys in inKeyFile for which the difference has already been printed(anything like a Set in Java)?
Edit: I think i can sort the inKeyFile and if last read key was same as the current key then i can skip

Answer (score 1):

To find the difference `file1 - file2` as the difference of sums of rows grouped by selected columns e.g., `1`, `2` (zero-based):

```
$ ./columnwise-sum-diff 1,2 file1 file
{"y|z": [4, 5, 6]}
```

where `columnwise-sum-diff` is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import json
import sys
from operator import itemgetter

def columnwise_sum(a, b):
    return tuple(x+y for x, y in zip(a, b)) # map(sum, zip(*args))

def columnwise_diff(a, b):
    return tuple(y-x for x, y in zip(a, b)) # b - a

def sum_file(filename, get_key, get_numbers):
    filesum = {}
    with open(filename) as file:
        for line in file:
            row = line.split(',')
            key = get_key(row)
            numbers = get_numbers(row)
            total = filesum.get(key)
            filesum[key] = columnwise_sum(total, numbers) if total else numbers
    return filesum

if len(sys.argv) != 4:
    sys.exit('Usage: columnwise-sum-diff <keycol1,keycol2> <file1> <file2>')

key_columns = sorted(map(int, sys.argv[1].split(',')))
get_key = itemgetter(*key_columns)
n = max(key_columns) + 1 # to the right of the key columns

def get_numbers(row, getcols=itemgetter(*range(n, n + 3))):
    return tuple(map(int, getcols(row)))

file1sum = sum_file(sys.argv[2], get_key, get_numbers)
file2sum = sum_file(sys.argv[3], get_key, get_numbers)
diff = {'|'.join(k): columnwise_diff(file2sum[k], file1sum[k])
        for k in file1sum.viewkeys() & file2sum.viewkeys()}
json.dump(diff, sys.stdout)
```

It produces json to simplify the structured data exchange.

Comment: `File "columnwise-sum-diff", line 36, in <module>
    for k in file1sum.viewkeys() & file2sum.viewkeys()}
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'viewkeys'
`

Comment: @Armali: [`dict.viewkeys()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.viewkeys)